Photon-induced excitations of electrons in interacting systems
We consider a two-spin system of the type
$$
H = E_{\uparrow} \sum_{i = 1, 2} c_{i, \uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{i, \uparrow}
+ E_{\downarrow} \sum_{i = 1, 2} c_{i, \downarrow}^{\dagger} c_{i, \downarrow}
$$
which is realized for example by considering two degenerate electronic states in the presence of an external magnetic field. The density of states
$$
\rho \equiv \rho(E) = \rho_{\uparrow} (E) + \rho_{ \downarrow} (E)
$$
of this system is now given as in the first picture, and in total there are four states that can be occupied by electrons.

It is now common knowledge, assuming that there is no conflict with the Pauli-principle, that one can excite an electron that is occupying the lower energy-level to the upper one  photon-absorption, if the photons possess an energy of $h \nu = E_{\uparrow} - E_{\downarrow} $.
If we now include certain [int]eractions, and compute the self-energy of the system, the electronic density of states changes $\rho \longmapsto \rho_{int}$ and I get something similar to the second picture.

Notice that the interacting density of states is also normalized to four (states)
$$
4 = \int \mathrm{d}E \rho ( E ) = \int \mathrm{d}E \rho_{int} ( E ).
$$
I would like to argue now, that one can also induce photon-induced transitions (assuming no complications with the Pauli-principle) from $\tilde{E}_{\downarrow}$ to $\tilde{E}_{\uparrow}$, since the density of states, integrated over that region, gives a number greater than one. (Hence it is possible for an electron to occupy these energy-levels.) So if I try to excite the system with photons of frequencies $h \tilde{\nu} = \tilde{E}_{\uparrow} - \tilde{E}_{\downarrow}$ this should be perfectly possible, right?
Is there a problem with my argument? I would say arguments like these are usually being done when one considers the densities of states that one obtains from DFT-calculations for electronic quasi-particles (since the potentials originating from the Hartree- and exchange-contribution are effectively a self-energy which modifies the non-interacting density of states), but I have never seen it in the context of spin-systems.

It is not clear what problem/hamiltonian leads to the second spectrum. Are you including additional finite terms in Hamiltonian (something like electrons coupled to a cavity - this could explain your spectrum)? Or are you considering absorption perturbatively - this is how absorption would be often treated in solids, which is suggested by the text.. but contradicts the picture (why should it change spectrum at all?)

The type of interaction doesn't really matter for my unclarity; it could be electron-electron-interactions or spin-dependent electron-phonon-interactions.

Now it is completely unclear - aren't you talking about photoexcitation? In this case the interaction is something like $\sum_{i,j}u_{ij}c_{i,\uparrow}^\dagger c_{j,\downarrow}+h.c.$. The question is how you treat this interaction - is this interaction with a cavity, which may result in mode splitting or is it just a photoexcitation, treated via Fermi golden rule or something like that.

Or perhaps, the interaction and photoexcitation are two different things in your case? Honestly, I am taken aback by the sentence "It is now common knowledge,..." - it suggests that you have no idea to where your Hamiltonian comes from, and what it physically means. Please do not be offended - it is not your fault - but it is frustrating that students are given model Hamiltonians, the meaning of which they do not understand, because they do not have appropriate background in condensed matter (although professors might not have it either sometimes.)

Dear Roger, the interactions and the photoexcitations are different things. The photoexcitations are neither included in the model-Hamiltonian, nor in the interactions. The unperturbed Hamiltonian is a typical model-Hamiltonian that one considers in atomic spectroscopy when a magnetic field is present, but it is here rewritten in second quantization. When one includes many-body-interactions one usually computes self-energies and subsequently Green-functions from which the DOS can be extracted, which was done for a concrete system, and depicted here in a simplified way.

Well, all I am trying to say in so many ways is that your question is unclear. Try to add references to support your claims and clarify what you know and what you don't know. Otherwise your Q. may remain unanswered.
